# AttributeError: 'Specificity' object has no attribute 'update_state_fn'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, metrics

I am trying to dump a model of [MIL package](https://github.com/rosasalberto/mil) and its metrics to the disk using pickle. I have no issues with the load function but when I try to extract the loaded contents (model, the metrics), I am getting an attribute error for the same.

I have added the code snippet for the metrics class here. You can also refer the trainer class from the author [here](https://github.com/rosasalberto/mil/blob/master/mil/trainer/trainer.py)

Is there any fix for this?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.backend import epsilon

from mil import metrics

class Metric(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    """ Custom base class for implementing a metric,
        each Metric subclass has to implement this methods. """
    def __init__(self, name, **kwargs):
        super(Metric, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        
    def update_state_fn(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        """ Update the state of the metric 
        Parameters
        ----------
        y_true : array-like containing the ground_truth
        y_pred : array-like containing the network predictions
        sample_weight : optional. weight more some predictions.
        """
        raise NotImplementedError
        
    def result(self):
        """ Get the result of a metric """
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    def reset_states(self):
        """ Reset the state of the metric """
        raise NotImplementedError
        
class Specificity(Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='specificity', **kwargs):
        super(Specificity, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.specificity = self.add_weight(name='specificity', initializer='zeros')
        self.specificity.assign(np.nan)
        self.tn = metrics.TrueNegatives()
        self.fp = metrics.FalsePositives()
        
    def update_state_fn(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):             
        self.tn.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
        self.fp.update_state(y_true, y_pred, sample_weight)
        
        tn = self.tn.result()
        fp = self.fp.result()
        
        value = tf.where(tn + fp == 0, np.nan, tn / (tn + fp + epsilon()))
        self.specificity.assign(value)
    
    def result(self):
        return self.specificity
    
    def reset_states(self):
        self.specificity.assign(np.nan)
        self.tn.reset_states()
        self.fp.reset_states()
```

I have added the entire code for calling this function: (from Github)

```
# importing dataset
from mil.data.datasets import musk1
# importing bag_representation
from mil.bag_representation import MILESMapping
# importing validation strategy
from mil.validators import LeaveOneOut
# importing final model, which in this case is the SVC classifier from sklearn
from mil.models import SVC
# importing trainer
from mil.trainer import Trainer
# importing preprocessing 
from mil.preprocessing import StandarizerBagsList
# importing metrics, which in this case are from tf keras metrics
from mil.metrics import AUC

# loading dataset
(bags_train, y_train), (bags_test, y_test) = musk1.load()

# instantiate trainer
trainer = Trainer()

# preparing trainer
metrics = ['spec']
model = SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, class_weight='balanced')
pipeline = [('scale', StandarizerBagsList()), ('disc_mapping', MILESMapping())]
trainer.prepare(model, preprocess_pipeline=pipeline ,metrics=metrics)

# fitting trainer
valid = LeaveOneOut()
history = trainer.fit(bags_train, y_train, sample_weights='balanced', validation_strategy=valid, verbose=1)

# printing validation results for each fold
print(history['metrics_val'])

# predicting metrics for the test set
trainer.predict_metrics(bags_test, y_test)

import pickle

with open('model_pkl.pkl', 'wb') as files:
    pickle.dump(trainer, files)

with open('/home/mylaptop/Res/model_pkl.pkl','rb') as sample_test:
  abc = pickle.load(sample_test)
```

Stack trace:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-84-9214b6d16ff4> in <module>
      1 with open('/home/mylaptop/Res/model_pkl.pkl','rb') as sample_test:
----> 2   abc = pickle.load(sample_test)

AttributeError: 'Specificity' object has no attribute 'update_state_fn'
```

Comment: Don't make us visit external links to see your code.  Post your code, and any error messages, directly in the question.

Comment: There is no reference to `update_state_fn` in the code you have shown, so it's unclear where the error is originating from.  Please edit to include the full error traceback.